# Android Studio Google Sign-In not working

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I am using Google sign-in for my app, and it does get called, but when it pops up, instead of asking which account I want to use, it says "This app requires the latest version of the Google play games app". And I am sure, that Google play games app is installed because I entered my account data into there.

**Edit:**
I am using API version 24 on my AVD

Comment: What version of android API are you using? What version of Android are you using on phone?

Comment: Which version of Google Play Games have you declared in your build.gradle file?

Comment: I am using the version "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.2.6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if your google play services version is 10.2.6. 
Else you will have to update it. 
Else specify a lower version like com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.8.0 in your gradle file and run.

Comment: @I.Renk Glad to have been of help :)